# Eclipse can't find Java after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse, openjdk, jdk

After upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 Eclipse 3.8 can't find any installed Java VM. I have the Sun JDK 1.7 and the openJDK7 installed.

I have tried modifying the eclipse.ini to point it to one of the installed Java VMs:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

This lets Eclipse start but it does not recognize any Java.

```
-vm
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java
```

With this Eclipse crashes at startup with the following error message:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java
```

Pointing to the java files in the respective jre directories has the same results.

Any ideas?

**Update**: I have updated the Oracle Java to 1.8. Now it doesn't crash Eclipse anymore and behaves exactly the same as openJDK7. Eclipse doesn't see either.

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

worked for me.